# differentiation of diagonalization of positive definite matrix

Tags: statistics, derivatives, diagonalization

I am trying to implement the derivative of the diagonalization a positive-definite matrix of size $n\times n$ wrt its $n(n+1)/2$ lower (or upper) components.
Just so that we agree on notations, I look for a decomposition of the shape $M = UDU^T$, with $U^TU =I_n$ and $D$ is diagonal (with positive diagonal terms since M is p.d.), such as the output of the eigen() function from R.
Thank you in advance !

Edit: I found a solution. I think that it may make scream people who do *real* maths, but I managed to confirm it numerically. Feel free to point if something seems wrong anyway.

To get the derivative of the eigenvalues, let $U_i$ be the $i^{th}$ column of U, and $D_i$ the corresponding eigenvalue. Let $M = \Sigma M_j e_j$, $(e_1,\ldots , e_{d(d+1)/2})$ being a basis of symmetric matrices.  Start from $U_i^T(M-D_iI)U_i = 0$. Differentiate to obtain $\partial U_i^T(M-D_iI)U_i/\partial M_{j} = 0$. Then, apply the product rule and cancel some stuff to obtain
$$ \partial D_i /\partial M_j= U_i e_j U_i^T $$

To get the eigenvectors, start from $(M-D_iI)U_i = 0$ and get $\partial (M-D_iI)U_i/\partial M_{j} = 0$. Then, applying the product rule, you get
$$ -(e_j - I \partial D_i /\partial M_j)U_i = (M-D_iI)\partial U_i/\partial M_{j}.$$
Here, it looks like you are screwed, because $(M-D_iI)$ is not invertible. But, because of the fact that $U^tU = I$, you will have $<\partial U_i/\partial M_{j},U_i>$ = 0. Then, the when multiplying $(M-D_iI)$, you lose one component that is always zero. Then you can go ahead and get
$$ -pseudoinv(M-D_iI)(e_j - I \partial D_i /\partial M_j)U_i = \partial U_i/\partial M_{j}.$$

Comment: Just note that the derivative won't exist when the matrix has more than one eigenvalue equal to each other.

Comment: Also, since the diagonal matrix is not uniquely defined, it's best to compute the derivative of each eigenvalue with respect to the matrix. This can be done by using implicit differentiation with the equation $$ \det(M_t-\lambda_tI) = 0$$